# Styles are not being applied to elements created in the setup function in vue

Tags: vue.js, vue-composition-api

So I am working on this mini website and I'm trying to not hard code repetitive elements in the template, so I thought I would a function to display them all.

```
<template>
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="skills" ref="canvas">
    </div>
</div>
```

```
import { ref, onMounted } from 'vue';
import MySkills from '../constants/skills';
export default {
    setup() {
        const skills = MySkills
        const canvas = ref(null);
        const displaySkills = () => {
            skills.forEach(skill => {
                const el = document.createElement('div');
                el.className = 'skill';

                el.innerText = skill.name;
                const level = document.createElement('span');
                level.className = 'level';
                level.innerText = skill.level;
                el.appendChild(level);
                canvas.value.appendChild(el);
            })
        }
        onMounted(() => {
            displaySkills();
        })
        return {
            canvas,
            displaySkills
        }
    }
}
```

the styles are in a separate file

```
.skill {
    padding: 10px;
    border-radius: 100px;
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
    background-color: aqua;
}

.level {
    position: absolute;
    top: -5%;
    left: 0%;
    padding: 5px;
    border-radius: 100px;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Now the ssue is that those styles are not being applied the `el` and `level` elements
please help!!!

Comment: How exactly is this separate file used? FWIW, you're trying to do what v-for does. Direct dom access without a good reason is discouraged in vue

Answer (score 0):

You should not access the DOM (`createElement`, `appendChild`) while working with Vue.
If you are new to Vue, `v-for` does exactly that, more info [in the official docs](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/list.html).
So your code would be:

```html
<template>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <!-- you should put a unique identifier in the key tag, if you don't have an id the name should be fine too -->
    <div class="skills" v-for="skill in MySkills" :key="skill.id">
      <your-skill-html>
        {{ skill.name }} etc
      </your-skill-html>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script setup>
  import MySkills from '../constants/skills';
</script>

<style>
  .skill {
    padding: 10px;
    border-radius: 100px;
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
    background-color: aqua;
  }

  .level {
    position: absolute;
    top: -5%;
    left: 0%;
    padding: 5px;
    border-radius: 100px;
    text-align: center;
  }

  /* or import "path/to/my-css-file.css" */
</style>
```

Please note that I'm using the `script setup` syntax but it's not required, it's just quicker to write since you can omit the `defineComponent` part and the return values.